# Why does this always point to a similar value?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

Out of curiosity, I ran this simple C program to see if I could index into a 2D array with one index:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int a[][5] = {
    {1,2,3,4,5},
    {6,7,8,9,10},
    {11,12,13,14,15},
    {16,17,18,19,20},
    {21,22,23,24,25}
  };
  printf("%d, %d\n", a[2][3], a[2*5 + 3]);
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling with `gcc -Wall` warned me that the third parameter to printf was an `int*`,so I dereferenced it and recompiled. This time, I noticed that the second value printed was a number always in the range 32764 - 32767 (both inclusive), and usually 32764 or 32765. Is there a reason for this or is it just random data?

Edit: I changed the third parameter to printf to `*a[2*5 + 3]` after receiving the warning, sorry I didn't make it clear

Comment: It's random data. I'm getting numbers like `1631363012`.

Comment: And I am getting values like [this](http://ideone.com/ZaAEDz).

Comment: And in any case, you are invoking UB, because `a[13]` is undefined in the code.

Comment: @itdoesntwork It's certainly not RANDOM DATA. But it's actually UB because, the passed value requires `"%p"` to print it.

Comment: Possibly you intended something like `(*a)[2*5 + 3]` or `a[0][2*5 + 3]`, to find `a[2][3]` by indexing as a 1D array?

Comment: In `*a[2*5 + 3]` the `*` dereferences `a[2*5 + 3]` rather than just the `a`... you need the parentheses so the dereference happens before the indexing brackets, like `(*a)[2*5 + 3]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes** it is random data because you are trying to dereference the memory address which is not defined.

`a[2 * 5 + 3]` returns the address of 14th row which does not exist in your case. And `*a[2 * 5 + 3]`  will be 1st element of 14th row.

Also as suggested by @iharob you should use `%p` instead of `%d`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print a pointer with the `"%d"` operator which is Undefined Behaviour. You must use `"%p"` for that.

What you want to do is possible but you are doing it wrong. You need to dereference the pointer again or you can cast to an `int *` like this

```
printf("%d, %d\n", a[2][3], ((int *) a)[2*5 + 3]);
```

you might also do this

```
printf("%d, %d\n", a[2][3], *(*a + 2*5 + 3));
```

Comment: In fact the op might be missing the point that `a[2*5 + 3]` is an `int[]`.